# How do I pass multi dimensional Data through a Keras Network?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, keras

I have some positional data consisting of `n` points of `2` dimensions (coordinates) per sample. I'd like to pass this data into my model and receive a similar output, also consisting of `n` points with `2` values each. However, when I try the following:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n * 2, input_shape=(n, 2)))
model.add(Dense(n * 2, activation="relu"))  # dense_X
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=1)
```

I get the following error message upon fitting my data:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_X to have shape (n, 2 * n) but got array with shape (n, 2)
```

My `X_train` has the shape `(number of samples, n, 2)` and `y_train` has the same.
Now, through trial and error, I found that replacing `dense_X` with `Dense(2, activation="relu")` will not yield an error, but this gives me only `2` resulting points, not `n`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Setting the node count of the final layer to 2 yields the correct answer based on what you have said. An input made as such: np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,2],[3,4]]]) with an identical output, when overfit yields the expected result.

Comment: The input shape needs to be of the format input_shape=(n_cols, ). Judging by what you have written n_cols is 2 in your case. You don't have to explicitly specify the number of rows of your data. The number of nodes 2**2 might not be sufficient, so you may have to increase it. You can specify an activation function in your input layer as well. It might be worth adding a couple more layers before the output layer. The hidden layers would be similar to the input layer without the input_shape parameter.The output should have 2 nodes if you want the model to output an array of n rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Looks like I wasn't clear enough, sorry about that. To be precise, I have m samples of n points with 2 coordinates. My output should be one sample of n points with two coordinates. Therefore my input shape should be at least be two dimensional + the wildcard for the Differenzsamples, right?